# Native linking error: warning: directory not found for option '-L

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am building an app with Xamarin.Studio for Mac. I added a library for reference than I removed it. Now when I am trying to build the application for iOS it give me this error:

```
/Users/crs/Projects/time.al/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5209: Native linking error: warning: directory not found for option '-L../../../Downloads/googleiosanalytics-3.14.0.1/samples/CuteAnimalsiOS/CuteAnimalsiOS' (MT5209) (time.al.iOS)
```

But I have removed this kind of library. Any idea how to remove this error

Comment: Go to your build settings and search for that path. You should find whatever option or setting is still referencing that library.

Comment: I cannot find build settings in Xamarin Studio. Where should I look?

Comment: I don't know in Xamarin. In Xcode, it is in the project settings. There are tabs for General, Capabilities, Info, Build Settings, etc.